# How can I select multiple textViews from the collection of textViews which is not in listview on long pressing

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, textview

I have a collection of `textViews` in a `LinearLayout`, I want them to select on long press. I tried this code but it didn't work...

```
    textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textView.setSelected(true);
            selected = 1;
            return false;
        }
    });
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(selected == 1){
                if(textView.getSelected())
                     textView.setSelected(false);
                else
                     textView.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried to search for `setOnLongPressListener` but didn't find anything like that.
Please suggest me any methods for the action I want.

Comment: Have you added `android:textIsSelectable="true"` for TextView ?

Comment: no. will above code work. if i'll do it..?

Comment: i tried it it's selecting some text of textView, but i want to select the textView itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to highlight textview when selected on long press. Try this:

```
textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
             boolean selected = !view.isSelected();
             view.setSelected(selected);
             view.setBackgroundColor(selected ? Color.RED : Color.TRANSPARENT);
             return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: i am getting a problem in your solution, which is that when i change the color of background the GradientDrawable which i set to background of textView is vanishing. is that any method to put on a transparent layer of color of width 100% and height equal to height of TextView which is wrap_content. like in whatsapp messenger when we select messages on long pressing...

Comment: My code will change background of your textview.  You should ask this on another question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put **true** in the TextView's **clickable** property in your xml file:

```
<TextView
 android:clickable="true"/>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Change your return type **false** to true inside setOnLongClickListener().

It triggers both- setOnLongClickListener() and setOnClickListener() method if you return false. So that can be the issue.

You can change the color of the background onLongClick to different.